# How does the default contact name field on case work?

Tags: custom-field, lookup, page-layout

There is a default field on the Case object that uses a lookup on Contact to display the contacts name.

I need to make a custom field on Case that displays a custom text field from the Contact object. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a formula field on Case where the formula is something like: `Contact.Custom_Field_API_Name__c` (use the Advanced Formula tab).  When you link the Contact to the Case, that field will auto-fill with whatever value is in `Custom_Field_API_Name__c` on the Contact

Answer (score 0):

The Contact name on the Case works as follows. when you tie an Account with the  Case and there is Account Team member related to the contact will get auto populated on the Case Contact Name. But to fulfill your requirement you may need to create a lookup.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the steps I would need to do?

Comment: From the comment I am understanding that you wants the steps to create Lookup to the Contact. Create a lookup field ( I think you know this step) and add filter condition on the lookup ( example all contacts whose account is the one on case) because to bring down number of results and make it easy to select

Comment: why would you need to create a lookup aside from the default lookup?